# Show that $\exists c \in \mathbb{R} : f(c) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such as $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) > 2$.

What could I do to show that $\exists c \in \mathbb{R} : f(c) = 0$ ?

At first I thought I could use the mean value theorem but it did not help me. In fact, I don't really understand why $f(x)$ couldn't be strictly positive $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Would you know how to proceed ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the mean-value theorem you get
$$
 \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} > 2
$$
for all nonzero $x$. It follows that
$$
 f(x)  \ge f(0) + 2x \text{ for } x > 0
$$
and
$$
 f(x)  \le f(0) + 2x \text{ for } x < 0
$$
so that $f$ necessarily takes both positive and negative values. Now conclude with the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much !

Comment: Beautiful proof.